# I've downloaded the GDAL-1.11.1 package but why can't I call on it in python?

Tags: python, gdal, mac

I have a Mac and am very new to this coding stuff..

I'm using a code that includes

```
import osgeo as gdal
```

and so I've downloaded GDAL from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/ which has a folder called "osgeo" and a python script called "gdal", but when I run the whole code I get the message "ImportError: No module named 'osgeo'"

Can someone give me the babysteps about how to import this correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is wrong.  Do this:

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

GDAL is a module of the osgeo package.  You don't ever import osgeo itself.  In Python a package is a convenient collection of modules and provides a 'name-space' for that collection.  So, you can drill down further and import specific functions or variables from a module within a package like this:

```
from aPackage import aModule.someFunction
```

The statement `from osgeo import gdal` fetches everything in the gdal module. Sometimes you only want parts of a module and it can be more efficient to just import what you need.  Don't worry about that for now.  In your case, the three most common imports you will do when using GDAl are

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import osr
```

GDAL gives you raster functionality.  OGR gives you vector functionality and OSR gives you spatial reference functionality.  Have a look at this excellent if old [tutorial](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/).  It will help you get started.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I'm still getting the same error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Mike/phenology.py", line 9, in <module>
    from osgeo import gdal
ImportError: No module named 'osgeo'

Answer (score 1):

You cannot only unzip the folder, you must install the module with `python setup.py install`but osgeo is a Python wrapper of the GDAL C++ library. Therefore you need to install first the GDAL library and then install the Python module witch uses the GDAL libraries

> Dependencies: * libgdal (1.11.0 or greater) and header files (gdal-devel)

You can compile and install yourself the GDAL C++ library and after the Python module but for Mac OS X there are many complete solutions (GDAL + osgeo installation):

- the [KyngChaos version](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks) installed in /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework for the Apple standard Python
- the [Homebrew version](http://brew.sh/) for the Homebrew Python version ([How to Install Python GDAL on OS X](http://www.davidlemayian.com/post/60791205171/how-to-install-python-gdal-on-os-x) for example)
- others as MacPorts or Fink solutions

Comment: I've tried downloading it using both methods but each time it asks me for a password? I tried inputting the password for my computer but that doesn't seem to work